# Using fscanf to read from tabbed file with ints and floats in C++

Tags: c++

I have looked for a day or so on StackOverflow and other sites, and I can't find a solution to my problem. There are some that are similar, but I can't seem to make them work.

I have a tab-delimited .txt file. One line contains a heading, and 500 lines after that each contain an integer, an integer, a float, an integer, and an integer, in that order. I have a function that is supposed to read the first and third values (the first integer and the float) from each line. It skips the first line. This is in a do-while loop, because I need to be able to process files of different lengths. However, it's getting stuck in the loop. I have it set to output the mean, but it just outputs zeros forever.

```
void HISTS::readMeans(int rnum) {
    int r;
    char skip[500];
    int index = 0; int area = 0; double mean = 0; int min = 0; int max = 0;

    FILE *datafile = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if(datafile == NULL) cout << "No such file!\n";
    else {
            //ignore the first line of the file
            r = fscanf(datafile,"%s\n",skip);
            cout << skip << endl; //just to check

            //this is the problematic code
            do {
                    r = fscanf(datafile,"%d\t%d\t%f\t%d\t%d\n",&index,&area,&mean,&min,&max);
                    cout << mean << " ";
            } while(feof(datafile) != 1)
    }
    fclose(datafile);
}
```

Here is a sample data file of the format I'm trying to read:

```
        Area        Mean        Min        Max
1       262144      202.448     160        687
2       262144      201.586     155        646
3       262144      201.803     156        771
```

Thanks!

Edit: I said I need to read the first and third value, and I know I'm reading all of them. Eventually I need to *store* the first and third value, but I cut that part for the sake of brevity. Not that this comment is brief.

Comment: Is it possible that some line of your stream doesn't match this format? In that case, fscanf() returns, leaving the stream as it was, which means it will never reach EOF.

Comment: I guess I'd be pretty surprised if that were the case. Can something look like a number but really be some other character? It's just a .txt file, but it gets generated by another program (ImageJ) so I suppose it's remotely possible. What would be a good way to tell?

Comment: @Gwen `while(feof(datafile) != 1)` can you put `;` (semicolon) after this and try ??

Comment: I tried that; thanks for catching the typo. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Gwen Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it C++ style,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream inf("file.txt");
  if (!inf) { exit(1); }
  int idx, area, min, max;
  double mean;

  while (inf >> idx >> area >> mean >> min >> max) {
    if (inf.eof()) break;
    std::cout << idx << " " << area << " " << mean << " " << min << " " << max << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It is :

1) Easy to read.

2) Less code, so less chance of error.

3) Correct handling of `EOF`.

Although I have left handling of first line, that is upto you.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way, but I'm using the ROOT C++ interpreter, and I have an old version which I can't get to work nicely with that format. I thought I'd have better luck asking about reading a file than I would asking about ROOT, since no one (even the people who use it) seem to know much about it. I might go back to that if I can't work anything else out, though.

Comment: @Gwen :) best of luck!

Comment: Okay, so I did end up doing it like this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ehm, `if (inf.eof()) break;` is a bad idea. Useless in the best case, dangerous in the worst as if the last line of the file isn't terminated by a newline (it may happen) that line will be skipped. Also `mean` should be a double or a float...

Comment: @Bob__ It's just useless, not dangerous. Stream unlike getline does not gobble newline. And yeah, `mean` should be double.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf returns the number of arguments read. Thus, if it returns less than 5 you should exit the loop.

Comment: I checked that, and it does exit the loop, but that still doesn't really fix the problem--it just exits the loop immediately, without ever reading anything.

Comment: What are the contents of skip when it does this? Is fscanf() greedily taking the whole file in the first read?

Comment: skip just has "Area" in it. I think %s just reads until the first whitespace. Which is fine, since I don't care about saving the information from the first line. Could that be causing the problem? Maybe the next thing fscanf() tries to read is the space after "Area"?

Comment: @Gwen Verify the format of the file using `cat -vet <file_name>`.

Comment: If 'skip' just has "Area", then your subsequent fscanf() reads will be incorrect, since you'll be starting on "\tMean..." and not the first line of input. Instead of that first fscanf() to swallow the first line, try using getline(), which will take the whole first line.

Answer (score 0):

OP ended up using `operator>>`, which is the correct way to do this in C++. However, for the interested C reader, there were a couple of issues in the code posted:

- `mean` was declared as `double` but read using the wrong format specifier `%f` instead of `%lf`.
- The first line wasn't completely read, but only the first token, `Area`.

A possible way to implement the desired task is as follows:

```
r = fscanf(datafile,"%[^\n]\n",skip);
//                    ^^^^^ read till newline

while ( (r = fscanf(datafile,"%d%d%lf%d%d",&index,&area,&mean,&min,&max)) == 5 ) {
    //                             ^^ correct format specifier for double
    // ...
}
```